# ¿Cómo evitar la carga de parámetros de un método a otro?

Tags: php, poo

Mi clase:

```
    class vista{

    private $_rutaCss = URL . 'public/css/';
    private $_rutaJs = URL . 'public/js/';
    private $_rutaImg = URL . 'public/img/';
    private $_rutaIcon = URL . 'public/img/favicon/';
    private $_rutaConf = DIR . 'protected/include/';
    private $_link;
    private $_archivo;
    private static $instancia;




    public function setCss(array $filecss) {
        foreach ($filecss as $css) {
            $this->_archivo = $this->_rutaCss . $css . ".css";
            if (@file_get_contents($this->_archivo, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH)) {
                $this->_link .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $this->_archivo . '" />';
            } else {
                echo "Archivo Css " . $css . ".css no encontrado<br />";
                echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . $this->_rutaCss . $css . '.css">' . $css . '</a><br />';
            }
        }
        return $this->_link;
    }

    public function setJs(array $filejs) {

        foreach ($filejs as $js) {
            $this->_archivo = $this->_rutaJs . $js . ".js";
            if (@file_get_contents($this->_archivo, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH)) {
                $this->_link .= '<script src="' . $this->_archivo . '" ></script>';
            } else {
                echo "Archivo Js " . $js . ".js no encontrado<br />";
                echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . $this->_rutaJs . $js . '.js">' . $js . '</a><br />';
            }
        }
        return $this->_link;
    }
 public function header($titulo = FALSE) {
        $cabecera = '';
        $titulo = isset($titulo) ? $titulo : 'Sin titulo';
        $cabecera .= "<title>" . $titulo . "</title>";
        $cabecera .= $this->setCss(['bootstrap.min', 'font-awesome.min']);
        return $cabecera;
    }

    public function footer(array $adicional = []) {
        $pie = '';
        $pie .= "<p> &copy; " . date("Y") . " - " . ((int) date("Y") + 1) . "</p>";
        $pie .= $this->setJs(['jquery-3.1.1.min', 'bootstrap.min']);
        return $pie;
    }

}
```

Así incluyo el archivo con la clase:

```
<?php
require_once './protected/include/config.php';
require_once './protected/include/vistaClass.php';
$vista = new vista();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <?php

    echo $vista->header('prueba');

    ?>

</head>
<body>
    <?php
    echo $vista->footer();
    ?>

</body>
```

Si los métodos se incluyen una sola vez, ¿por qué en el html se muestra así?:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">


                <title>prueba</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/pagina/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/pagina/public/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <p> &copy; 2016 - 2017</p>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/pagina/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/pagina/public/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <script src="http://localhost/pagina/public/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">/script>
<script src="http://localhost/pagina/public/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->_link` es una variable que tiene un scope dentro de toda tu clase y tu estás agregando datos a ella, debes limpiarla **antes** de volver a usarla para otra cosa si no quieres que tenga los datos anteriores:

```
public function setJs(array $filejs) {
    $this->_link = ''; //limpiamos la variable antes de usarla en este llamado...
    foreach ($filejs as $js) {
        $this->_archivo = $this->_rutaJs . $js . ".js";
        if (@file_get_contents($this->_archivo, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH)) {
            $this->_link .= '<script src="' . $this->_archivo . '" ></script>';
        } else {
            echo "Archivo Js " . $js . ".js no encontrado<br />". // no es necesario un doble echo
             '<a target="_blank" href="' . $this->_rutaJs . $js . '.js">' . $js . '</a><br />';
        }
    }
    return $this->_link;
}
```

Espero te ayude.